# Difference between .sbt/repositories and resolvers

Tags: scala, sbt

I've initially placed the Hortonworks HDP repository that I need to download the appropriate HBase and Phoenix libraries for my system in `$HOME/.sbt/repositories`, which worked fine.

I then decided that I'd rather have all non-standard repositories in the `resolvers` of my `build.sbt` file and run `sbt clean update`. However, when I do that I receive `unresolved dependency: org.apache.hbase#hbase-client;...`, where the ellipsis indicates the version I'm using. I think I'm missing something fundamental or is what I'm trying to achieve plain wrong?

The repo I'm talking about is:

```
hortonworks-hdp: http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/
```

And when I added it with (as per the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html)):

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("hortonworks", url("http://...")
```

I am behind a proxy but when the repo is added to the `repositories` file it works, so I doubt it's related to that fact.

Comment: What is the url that you are providing ?

Comment: The same as in the line I mentioned: `http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/`. The only import I have is `import sbt._`, from which I use the `url` method.

Comment: What is your sbt version?

Comment: I'm running 0.13.8

Comment: what about `resolvers += "Hortonworks Releases" at """http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/"""`

Comment: That did the trick! It's a Maven2 repository, so it should use the `at` syntax. It's in the documentation.